# How to use If-Then Conditional Across Workbooks in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, sum

I want to use if-then statement across two workbooks.

I've defined x as Long but x does not appear to hold the value of the sum of all cells in column B

But the code looks right, any thoughts?

```
Sub mycode()


       Dim x As Long


       myRange = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1", _ 
       Range("B1").End(xlDown))


       x = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange)    '<<does not seem to hold value



      If Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = x Then

         MsgBox ("values equal")

      Else

         MsgBox ("please review values")

      End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` at the very top of the module, then declare all variables. `Dim myRange As Range`. Then add `Set` before `myRange = ...`.

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work (msgbox says please review when clearly the sum of the range in one workbook equals the cell in another workbook

Comment: Do any of the values have numbers after the decimal point?

Comment: They do not, but most likely would in the future

Comment: Then you can't use `As Long`. I'd get rid of `x` entirely and check if the value equals the sum.

Comment: you need `As Double` . Also you might not be reliably taking the last row.

Comment: you should also debug the MyRange.Address to see if it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Or just do a sum on the entire column and scrap finding the last row, unless you specifically don't want the entire column. `Sum` can handle an entire column pretty easily. Also remove the parentheses following the `MsgBox`.

Comment: lol can I have an example set out

Answer (score 0):

As an example:

```
Sub MyCode()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2)

    If Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange) Then
        MsgBox "Values equal"
    Else
        MsgBox "Please review values"
    End If
End Sub
```